# JPA Hibernate JOIN ... ON ... AND

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM phaseinproject as pip JOIN projectinrelease pir 
ON pip.projectInRelease_id = pir.id
JOIN releaseperiod as rp ON pir.release_id = rp.id
JOIN releasestructure as rs ON rs.id = rp.releaseStructure_id
JOIN phaseinreleasestructure as pirs ON pirs.releaseStructure_id = rs.id
JOIN releasephase as rlp ON rlp.id = pirs.phase_id 
AND rlp.id = pip.phase_id
```

This query works totally fine. I get three results (the amount I expect).

I convert this query to the following HQL query:

```
            TypedQuery<PhaseInProjectOverview> findPhasesInRelease = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW nl.dashboard.dto.out.PhaseInProjectOverview(phaseInProject.id, phase.name, phaseInProject.startDate, phaseInProject.plannedEndDate, phaseInProject.endDate) FROM PhaseInProject phaseInProject "
                + "JOIN phaseInProject.projectInRelease projectInRelease "
                + "JOIN projectInRelease.release release "
                + "JOIN release.releaseStructure releaseStructure "
                + "JOIN releaseStructure.phaseInReleaseStructures phaseInReleaseStructure "
                + "JOIN phaseInReleaseStructure.phase phase "
                + "WHERE release.id = :releaseId ORDER BY phaseInReleaseStructure.position, phaseInProject.startDate", PhaseInProjectOverview.class);
        findPhasesInRelease.setParameter("releaseId", releaseId);
        return findPhasesInRelease.getResultList();
```

No matter what I try: I get 6 results, because HQL does not seem to support the `"JOIN ... ON ... AND ..."` sql syntax.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

edit:
I added my own answer with the used solution. Thank you all for the answers/pointers.

Comment: Does HQL support old join syntax? (select ... from tab1, tab2 ... where ...)

Comment: JPQL has an "ON" keyword in the JOIN, which you aren't using. You also don't state what is the SQL generated by this JPQL query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the with keyword: `phaseInReleaseStructure.phase phase WITH phase.id = phaseInProject.phase_id` - this should result in SQL like `releasephase as rlp ON rlp.id = pirs.phase_id AND rlp.id = pip.phase_id`

Alternatively just add that condition in the where clause:

```
... WHERE release.id = :releaseId AND phase.id = phaseInProject.phase_id ...
```

Comment: It doesn't seem WITH can be used with multiple entities. When I try to use this I get the following error:
HQL error: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements

Comment: @Sverro2 oh right, that limitation still seems to exist (unfortunately), forgot about that. So you'll have to use the "where"-route or a subselect. For more information, see here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7321 - I hope that will be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with an extra WHERE clause:

```
phase.id = phaseInProject.phase.id
```

Now I get the results I was expecting.
The 'WITH' keyword does not seem to work with multiple entities. When I try, I get an exception:

```
HQL error: with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements
```

When trying to use the 'ON' syntax like `JOIN phaseInReleaseStructure.phase phase ON phase.id = phaseInProject.id`, I get another error:

```
unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 473
```